# Magento: footer list alignment left in each column

Tags: xml, magento, footer

I am tuning existing magento template. Somewhy my footer's list aligns differently depending on cms page.

**Current Home Page footer:**

[image: home page footer list]

**Other Pages Footer (desired to be on all pages including home page)**

[image: desired home page footer]

As I understood footer is being applied to every page through the page.xml file. (Pls, correct me if I am wrong) When I installed the template, the alignment was the same on every page and I have not modified the page.xml.

Where footer's list alignment can be changed into left in each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by modifying my styles.css file, which is located here:

```
skin/frontend/default/mytheme/css/styles.css
```

by adding following snippet to the bottom:

```
.footer-col-content, .block .block-content, .box-collateral-content {
display: block !important;
height: 100% !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
text-align: left;
}
.footer h4 {
text-align: left;
}
```